90s/early 2000's thriller movie - Villain is a large, stocky,bulky,and bald criminally insane asylum inmate, protagonist is a heroine with a daughter
Made in US, though I'm not sure if its direct-to-video or had a theatrical release. Another trait that the villain has is that he is super strong and quite intelligent.
Story points:

It takes place in an asylum/correctional facility
Heroine is trapped in building with the villain (apparently, the building is under lock down).
At one point, the heroine meets a janitor/maintenance guy who apparently has the way out. Eventually they are separated, and the guy fights the villain. During the fight, the guy swallows the key. The fight ends when steam appears, and the villain drags the guy into the steam, and the guy shouts "noooooooo"
The heroine and villain meet, and the guy throws the bloody key onto the floor (the implication is that the villain gorily retrieved the key from the guys body) and announces that he will take her daughter from her mothers house.
Later, a swat team arrives at the facility and tries to apprehend the villain, but they all end up dead.
The daughter is kidnapped, and the last thing I can remember is that the villain and heroine fight (I think underground) and the villain ends up electrocuted to death.


Sounds Like Dark Asylum from 2001, where psychiatrist Dr Maggie Belham is locked in an abandoned asylum and a bald inmate (played by Larry Drake) stalks her. 
A janitor called Quitz (played by Judd Nelson) helps her. 
Dark Asylum iMdb Entry
Has pretty bad scores on Rotten Tomato, Meta Critic and iMdb so would assume a straight to video release for this bad boy.

Thats the movie I'm looking for, thank you :)
